# Converting division of int to int to a decimal is giving 0

Tags: c#

I came up with a formula to keep numbers a simple `int` and was surprised to see that the following was producing a 0.

```
var x = 45;
var y = 100;
var z = Convert.ToDecimal(x / y * 100);
```

In the above example, it almost seems ridicilous that I'm dividing by `100`, then multiplying by `100` but in most cases, the `x` and `y` values are not nice integers.

When my `x` and `y` values end up being integers, the above conversion produces a `0`. Why is that?

Comment: Because when you divide an integer with another integer the decimal result is not considered. 45 / 100 = 0

Comment: Because `floor(45/100)` = 0, and then `0 * 100` = 0.

Comment: Just cast one of your integers to decimal ((decimal)x / y) * 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X / Y = 0.45

Int conversion of 0.45 is 0.

Therefore 0 * 100 = 0.

Therefore Convert.ToDecimal(0) is 0.

Comment: So, I need to `Convert.ToDecimal(x/y)` first, then continue with the rest of the computation?

Comment: Try converting to decimal one of them first, or define them as decimal from the beginning, if it's possible.

Comment: @Sam You can simply do `x / (Decimal)y * 100`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This does look a bit odd, but the problem there is with the order the expressions are evaluated: first the arguments of Convert are evaluated, and that is done inintegers. That’s why the result is truncated.

You should replace the conversation with an expression that forces evaluation in decimals:

```
var z = 100M * x / z;
```